# Items added to RecycleList only in Debugging mode or when the screen is locked

Tags: android, kotlin

I am doing the searching and sorting when request data from the API but the results do not "come through" until I lock the screen or do put a breakpoint. What might be the reason for this bug and is it a bug at all. Here's my request code:

```
fun SearchInServer(SearchString: String): MutableList<SearchResult>{
    val url = "https://mysite/api/search/"+SearchString
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val values = mutableListOf<SearchResult>()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    // val point
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("False")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response){
            val body = response.body()?.string()
            val results: List<SearchResult> = Gson().fromJson(body, object: TypeToken<List<SearchResult>>(){}.type)
            results.forEach() {
                Log.v("res:", it.result)
                values.add(SearchResult(it.result, it.type, it.id))

            }
        }
    })
    Log.v("sizee", values.size.toString())
    return values
}
```

Comment: This code has actually nothing to do with RecyclerView, can you please adapt your title?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you're making an asynchronous call on search, the `values` was returned immediately from the block with empty size.

When in debugging mode, it probably somehow conveniently gave it just enough time for the data to return. And the same happened when you came back from lock screen, your views were triggered to redraw.